# How to execute ForEach loop 100 times in Jmeter?

Tags: json, foreach, automation, httprequest, jmeter-5.0

I have a thread group with loop count set to 5. Inside it, I have used a JSON extractor with `1st request` which creates a total of 100 variables with `purchaseOrderId_1` pattern. I used it in ForEach controller next so the loop shoud execute 100 times ideally. Inside the ForEachLoop, I have a while controller, which executes the child requests 5 times until all the 5 rows of data in Csv Dataset config is read. The goal is to run the `3rd request` 5 times for one value of output variable of ForEach controller and in the end, 500 times for the 100 values. The `3rd request` should run 2500 times in total. But, the test stops after executing the `3rd request` 5 times only for `purchaseOrder_1`.
[Screenshot of my test plan flow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V14y6.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a lot of nesting. I tried to interpret your statements and created a test plan. Please check if this is the requested pattern you are expecting.

[image]

This is the [Sample JMX](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u1VsiC8OnRTUYQcpKdN_14lwhkRvpjX4/view?usp=sharing)
CSV File [csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VOvNkpJmbTEh9B5P1Za-nPBhZbf_lEmm/view?usp=sharing)

**Note**: Update CSV file path after you download both the files

[image]

Comment: I looked at the script and did the same as you and replaced the while controller with loop controller set to 0. But still, the foreach controller loop ran only once and the debug sampler results after foreach controller also couldn't be seen in View Results Tree.

Comment: check settings for JSON extractor. esp. the expression and you need -1 'Match No.'

Comment: Match No is set to -1 and I have verified the expression with Json path evaluator so I don't see anything wrong there.

Comment: could you share json you are trying to parse? and output from `debug sampler`